# Visual Studio 2017, F7 not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I still have F7 as my global `View code` key, but it doesn't work.
My `F7` key on keyboard is not broken (because I can use F7 in other app)
How can I detect what happened with my F7 key in Visual Studio?

[image: I still have F7 as Global View code]

Comment: Accordingly to developercommunity.visualstudio.com the upcoming release (15.7.4.) should fix that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some tries, I've added F7 to anything related to "ViewCode" option, than it works again,

[image]

Comment: For who minus this, what did you expected for?

Answer (score 4):

> The Web Tools team added a new command in 15.7 that supports
>   switching between a Razor View and its C# code file, and mapped it to
>   F7 because that's a common mapping for similar commands. However, we
>   didn't realize that this overlaps with the build command in certain
>   keyboard schemes and needs to be removed from those schemes.
>
> We are working on a fix that we will push out very soon. In the
>   meantime, you can unblock yourself with the following workaround.
>
> - Go to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard
> - In "Show commands
>     containing" type "ToggleRazorView"
> - Select "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ToggleRazorView"
> - Next to "Shortcuts for selected command" click "Remove"

Answer by Vino Wang from [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247269/f7-does-not-switch-to-code.html)

UPDATE:

> Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed the problem in an upcoming
>   release (15.7.4.) Thank you for helping us build a better Visual
>   Studio!

Finaly! :D

Answer (score 0):

**Build.Solution** is also assigned to **F7**. In my case, that's the shortcut that does not work.

Generally, in case of shortcut issue, find the command you that the shortcut does not work for you, click "Remove" shortcut, then reassign again the same shortcut. VS will show in "*Shortcut currently used by*" command that uses the same shortcut and causes conflict.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the F7 shortcut that is attached to:

ToggleRazorView

Comment: thanks for comment, After some tries, I've update some more setting then F7 work again, 
https://imgur.com/a/s1dLq5A